# Enols and enolates in biosynthetic pathways

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

I'm having a little trouble unterstanding the way organisms carry out aldol and claisen type reactions. I'm familiar with the laboratory procedures to which I understand there is a correlation.

Inside a cell there are no strong bases, since their existence would lead to the destruction of proteins. However, the reactions mentioned above, need a decent base in order to occur. From what I've read, the presence of enzymes is what obviates the need for a strong base, leading to enolates existing for a minimal ammount of time. On the other hand though, I've read in some notes that these procedures are carried out by the enol form, not the enolate. So my question is what kind of nucleophile is formed in the beggining of these reactions?

Comment: I recommend finding a good reference on polyketides. That will get you started.

Comment: You mean a generally accpeted book? I use "medicinal natural products" from Dewick. Is doesn't suffice?

Comment: That's the one I used. It's decent enough.